# How can I get a Keras models' history after loading it from a file in Python?

Tags: python, keras

I have saved a `keras` model as a `h5py` file and now want to load it from disk.

When training the model I use:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
H = model.fit(....)
```

When the model is trained, I want to load it from disk with

```
model = load_model()
```

How can I get `H` from the `model` variable? It unfortunately does not have a `history` parameter that I can just call. Is it because the `save_model` function doesn't save history?

Comment: Saving a model just keeps model weights and architecture. `history` object is a dictionary. You can save dictionaries as `json` files or you can use `CSVLogger` callback to log your training history into a text file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that Keras hasn't implemented the possibility of loading the history directly from a loaded model. Instead you have to set it up in advance. This is how I solved it using `CSVLogger` (it's actually very convenient storing the entire training history in a separate file. This way you can always come back later and plot whatever history you want instead of being dependent on a variable you can easily lose stored in the RAM):

First we have to set up the logger before initiating the training.

```
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log', separator=',', append=False)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

The entire log history will now be stored in the file *'training.log'* (the same information you would get, by in your case, calling `H.history`). When the training is finished, the next step would simply be to load the data stored in this file. You can do that with pandas `read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
log_data = pd.read_csv('training.log', sep=',', engine='python')
```

From here on you can treat the data stored in `log_data` just as you would by loading it from `K.history`.

More information in [Keras callbacks docs.](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

Comment: In addition to the possibility to read it back using `pandas`, is there also a way to load back a history file (saved with `CSVLogger()` as you mentioned) as an original `History()` object? Just 'as if' it were freshly computed from `model.fit()`?

Comment: @s.k By using `CSVLogger` the history file is saved in .csv format by default. If I understand your purpose with loading it that way is to continue training you model. Then, you set argument `append=True` as in `keras.callbacks.callbacks.CSVLogger(filename, separator=',', append=True)` while at the same time specifying the `initial_epoch` argument to the epoch you want to continue training on when fitting the model onto the data again. See the documentation for [callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) as well as for [fitting sequential models](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).

Comment: @Jakob Is there a way to do this without pandas e.g. with `csv` built-in or numpy?

Comment: @Jakob How does one map the dataframe structure to the history object's structure?

Comment: @jtlz2 Referring to loading the `training.log` file with `csv`? You should be able to find something in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). There's a useful example at the top. As for the other question - I believe it warrants opening a new SO question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `pickle` to save the history object threw a whole host of errors. As it turns out you can instead use `pickle` on `H.history` instead of `H` to save your history file!

Kind of annoying having to have a model and a history file saved, but whatever