# Find the number of epochs of a loaded Keras model

Tags: python, keras

I usually load my Keras models using the load_model() method. Is it possible to obtain the number of epochs a model was trained for after loading it again?

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1766) mentions the following hack:

```
r = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5)
n_epochs = len(r.history['loss'])
```

However, that's not exactly what I want as I would like to obtain the number of epochs from the loaded models.

Comment: The number of epochs trained is a value that is not stored in model summary, which is the detailed source on design of any keras model.

Comment: How about storing the epochs using Keras `CSVLogger` during training? You'll get validation scores while at the same time keeping track of your epochs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot obtain the history after loading a model as the saved model keeps only the architecture and the weights. So you can't have the number of epochs of a loaded model. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843265/how-can-i-get-the-a-keras-models-history-after-loading-it-from-a-file-in-python) SO question.