# Keras: By loading saved model from local directory how to plot graph of accuracy and loss (history) of saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

During training I forgot to store model history like this:

history = model.fit( trainX, trainY, …).
And I saved the model to local directory by model.save(...)

Now I need the model accuracy and loss to plot its graph. How can I get those accuracy and loss of each epoch(history). Or I have to train model again.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the a keras models' history after loading it from a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843265/how-can-i-get-the-a-keras-models-history-after-loading-it-from-a-file-in-python)