# History plot from pre train network keras hd5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to draw a history plot from a pretrain network in keras, I searched a lot about this situation but I couldn't find anything.
Can  anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843265/how-can-i-get-a-keras-models-history-after-loading-it-from-a-file-in-python

Comment: @AloneTogether Thank you, but I saved model I can not retrain again I should do something with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Once the model is saved ,You can load the model then train with the same or a new Dataset and then use history to see its performance. Here is a toy example for reference.

```
model.save("my_model/model.h5")

#Reloading the model and training with new data

reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model/model.h5")
history = reconstructed_model.fit(test_input, test_target , epochs = 10)

#Plotting history of model
print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])

plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```